# Change default applications for all users

Tags: users, default-programs

Changing the default application for a given file type is relatively easy, but is there a way to do so for all users of a machine?

Answer (score 2):

Default file associations of the system are overridden systemwide by the file /etc/xdg/mimeapps.list. Changes to that file will be in effect for all users, however in as far as the user has not set his own preferences. The user specific preferences are registered in ~/.config/mimeapps.list, and override the systemwide ones.

So to systematically implement changed defaults to all users, you would need to remove mimeapps.list in each of the users directories.

Preferences set by the user take